# Laravel : Same Routing

Tags: laravel, routes

I have two routes

```
Route::get('/{order}/{filter}',array());  
Route::get('/staticWord1/staticWord2',array());
```

Problem is when I use `Route::get('/staticWord1/staticWord2',array());` , it uses the first route.

I have a different Controller for this. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I dont want to be rude or smth, but when you think about it answer is pretty logical...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to move your static route before your wildcard route

`Route::get('/staticWord1/staticWord2',array());
 Route::get('/{order}/{filter}',array());`

because you have a wildcard route before your static route, wildcard route will catch any matches and stop searching for subsequent routes.